# Change type of a variable inside an if scope

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++){
    if (i == 3)
        char i[3] = "abc";
    std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

So the problem is that `char i[3]` is only scoped inside the if and if I try to `cout` it in the if sentence it will print `"abc"` as expected but outside the if sentence it doesn't work, I could call it as if it's not sticky. So how can I declare it so it works outside of the if sentence and I don't want to add a `cout` inside the if sentence and I don't want to change the `cout` in the for loop because on my actual program I am printing a table.

---

**Update**: here is my actual code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#define pi 3.14159265359

double d2r(int deg) {
    double rad = (pi * deg) / 180;
    return rad;
}

int main() {
    int sw = 2;
    cout << "Deg" << "\t" 
        << "Sin" << "\t"
        << "Cos" << "\t"
        << "Tan" << "\t"
        << "\n";
    for (int deg = 2; deg <= 90; deg += 2) {
        double A = sin(d2r(deg));
        double B = cos(d2r(deg));
        double C = tan(d2r(deg));
        if (abs(B) < 0.00009)
            B = 0;
        if (abs(C) > 100)
            char C[4] = "Inf";
        cout << setprecision(3) << fixed
            << deg << setw(sw) << "\t"
            << A << setw(sw) << "\t"
            << B << setw(sw) << "\t"
            << C << setw(0) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare char i[3] before the if statement and define it in the if statement

Comment: What you do is name your char array something other than "I" and scope it outside of your loop (e.g. inside main).  From there it will be accessible inside your loop.

Comment: You can't change the type of `i` in the loop. If you move `char i[]` up one scope then it will conflict with the loop's `i` (can't have two variables with the same name declared in the same scope).  If you move `char i[]` to an even higher scope, then the loop's `i` will have priority inside the loop. So, what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Question: what should be printed on loops 1 and 2, before char i[3] gets initialized?

Comment: I would use something like this: `for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { if (i == 3) { std::cout << "abc"; } else { std::cout << i; } std::cout << "\n"; }` Or this: `for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { std:string s; if (i == 3) { s = "abc"; } else { s = std::to_string(i); } std::cout << s << "\n"; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Please take a look at my actual program https://pastebin.com/bCVFGB3r

Comment: @Shayan: that information belongs in your question, not on an external site.  I have edited your question for you this time.  Next time, please do it yourself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The 2nd code of yours (the one after "Or this:") actually is more simple for me to understand, I don't know about ostringstream.

Comment: @Shayan: the 1st code (before "Or this:") doesn't use `std::ostringstream`. It is just a simply `if` statement to call two different `cout` statements. The code in my answer uses `std::ostringstream`. But, in any case, [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) is just like `std::cout` except that it outputs the formatted text to a `std::string` instead of to the process's stdout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the type of `C` like you are attempting.  You need separate `cout <<` statements for different data types, eg:

```
cout << setprecision(3) << fixed
     << deg << setw(sw) << "\t"
     << A << setw(sw) << "\t"
     << B << setw(sw) << "\t";

if (abs(C) > 100)
    cout << "Inf";
else
    cout << C;

/* alternatively:
(abs(C) > 100) ? (cout << "Inf") : (cout << C);
*/

cout << setw(0) << "\n";
```

Alternatively, format a `std::string` based on whatever criteria you need, and then output that string, eg:

```
std::ostringstream oss;

if (abs(C) > 100)
    oss << "Inf";
else
    oss << setprecision(3) << fixed << C;

/* alternatively:
(abs(C) > 100) ? (oss << "Inf") : (oss << setprecision(3) << fixed << C);
*/

cout << setprecision(3) << fixed
     << deg << setw(sw) << "\t"
     << A << setw(sw) << "\t"
     << B << setw(sw) << "\t"
     << oss.str() << setw(0) << "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own I/O manipulator, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#define pi 3.14159265359

double d2r(int deg) {
    double rad = (pi * deg) / 180;
    return rad;
}

struct inf_if_greater_magnitude
{
    inf_if_greater_magnitude(double val, double limit) : val(val), limit(limit) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, inf_if_greater_magnitude const& iig)
    {
        if (std::isinf(iig.val) or std::isnan(iig.val) or (std::abs(iig.val) > iig.limit))
            return os << "Inf";
        else
            return os << iig.val;
    }

    double val;
    double limit;
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    int sw = 2;
    cout << "Deg" << "\t" 
        << "Sin" << "\t"
        << "Cos" << "\t"
        << "Tan" << "\t"
        << "\n";
    for (int deg = 2; deg <= 90; deg += 2) {
        double A = sin(d2r(deg));
        double B = cos(d2r(deg));
        double C = tan(d2r(deg));
        if (abs(B) < 0.00009)
            B = 0;
        cout << setprecision(3) << fixed
            << deg << setw(sw) << "\t"
            << A << setw(sw) << "\t"
            << B << setw(sw) << "\t"
            << inf_if_greater_magnitude(C, 100) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Expected results:

```
...
84  0.995   0.105   9.514
86  0.998   0.070   14.301
88  0.999   0.035   28.636
90  1.000   0.000   Inf
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0da21c8ef5579f95

Further refactoring could give you something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#define pi 3.14159265359

double d2r(int deg) {
    double rad = (pi * deg) / 180;
    return rad;
}

struct output_tan
{
    output_tan(double val) : val(val) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, output_tan const& iig)
    {
        if (std::isinf(iig.val) 
         or std::isnan(iig.val) 
         or (std::abs(iig.val) > 100))
            return os << "Inf";
        else
            return os << iig.val;
    }

    double val;
};

struct output_cos
{
    output_cos(double val) : val(val) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, output_cos const& iig)
    {
        auto v = iig.val;
        if (v < 0.00009) v = 0;
        return os << v;
    }

    double val;
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    int sw = 2;
    cout << "Deg" << "\t" 
        << "Sin" << "\t"
        << "Cos" << "\t"
        << "Tan" << "\t"
        << "\n";
    for (int deg = 2; deg <= 90; deg += 2) {
        cout << setprecision(3) << fixed
            << deg << setw(sw) << "\t"
            << sin(d2r(deg)) << setw(sw) << "\t"
            << output_cos(cos(d2r(deg))) << setw(sw) << "\t"
            << output_tan(tan(d2r(deg))) << "\n";
    }
}
```